# Why I am getting ' Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/modulerr'

Tags: angularjs

```
<html ng-app="demoapp">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var demoapp = angular.module('demoapp', []);

        demoapp.controller('SimpleController',function ($scope){
            $scope.customer = [
                {name: "Deepak" , city: "Bhubaneswar"},
                {name: "Sivaji" , city: "Banglore"}
            ];
            $scope.addCustomer = function($scope){
                $scope.customer.push({ name: $scope.newCustomer.name ,city: $scope.newCustomer.city});
            }
        }); 

        demoapp.config(function ($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/',{
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/view1.html'
                })
                .when('/view2',{
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/view2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        });

    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
```

Could any please suggest me what going wrong here?Why I am getting error. I am newbie to Angular please help. I think there is some issue with the config portion. But I am not able to debug it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add angular-route script

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Add ngRoute as dependency

```
var demoapp = angular.module('demoapp', ["ngRoute"]);
```

You should define controller like this.

```
demoapp.controller('SimpleController',["$scope", function ($scope){
    $scope.customer = [
         {name: "Deepak" , city: "Bhubaneswar"},
         {name: "Sivaji" , city: "Banglore"}
    ];
        $scope.addCustomer = function($scope){
            $scope.customer.push({ name: $scope.newCustomer.name ,city: $scope.newCustomer.city});
        }
}]);
```

Comment: Angular route script is compulsory? I was reffering to the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM . But nothing such mentioned over there. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, if you are using angularjs 1.2+. They removed ngRoute module into seperate file since [angular ui.router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) is really popular.